# .Net 6 Web API configuration for service-2-service AuthN/AuthZ using Azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-authentication

I have created an on-premise .Net 6 Web API and have successfully implemented authN using Azure (app registration > access_token).
This api is accessed publically by an external vendor in a service-2-service way.

Because the controller actions need to have AuthZ using [RBAC (Role-based access control)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) I started searching on how to accomplish this for my scenario.

What I did is, create app roles on the API app registration and create a 2nd app registration (client) that has a "Read" role, now I can generate a separate access_token but  it seems I have no way to check the role in the API?

[image]

[image: Client app regstration]

When using the **client** app registrations client_id and client_secret I only receive the access_token, no information on roles!

[image]

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "TOKENHERE"
}
```

What I need is proper Role checking using [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-6.0) **without a user** but I'm missing some crucial information on how to set this up properly on Azure and in the API bootstrapper. Roles, scopes, claims, ..?

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: From the screen shots it looks like you've setup your Azure AD App Registration correctly, which controls Authentication to your Function App. In terms of Authorization if you aren't using Azure API Manager I believe you will need to pass the `ClainsPrincipal` to the function execution and then write code to verify the groups that you want. Does this post help? https://medium.com/medialesson/role-based-authorization-in-azure-functions-with-azure-ad-and-app-roles-b1fed5714c91

Comment: Thanks for the link @Kane, but the API is running on IIS hosted on-prem. And there are no users to assign. Just giving access to another API calling mine but with authZ preferably.

Comment: Okay your comment provides a little more context. Assuming the authorizing App Reg is delegated you should be able to call the MS Graph API to get the groups using the bearer token. Alternatively if you have access to the ID_token this can be configured to include the groups.

Comment: Did you try decoding the generated access token in https://jwt.ms/?

Comment: @SrideviM, I decoded it but it's unclear for me what to do next. (use the claims to authorize the actions in the API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created **`App roles`** on the API App registration ***same*** as you like below:

[image]

I created another App registration for client and added **`Service.Read`** role by granting consent like below:

[image]

I generated access token for the application using **`Client Credentials`** grant type via Postman like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]

Using ***token endpoint URL***, you will only get tokens in the **response** without displaying claims.

You can find the **`claims`** like roles, scp etc... only when you **decode** the token like below:

[image]

In order to use the **claims to authorize** the actions in the API, you can build and register **`policies`** like below:

**In Program.cs:**

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.AddPolicy("Policy_Name", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Service.Read")); });

app.UseAuthorization();
```

**In Controller file:**

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "Policy_Name")]  
public class YourClass : Controller {}
```

Please **refer** the below documents to get complete code samples:

[Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Role based access using client credentials by user4864425](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62427987/role-based-access-using-identity-server-4-and-client-credentials-grant-type)

Comment: Thanks! That seems like what I was after, I will try this and report back with findings. The only thing that seems a bit weird is that you need to add an app registration for each role you have (which we both did) because you need different access_tokens (with that role in it). Is this the recommended way for client credential flow login and authorization in a .Net web api?

Comment: Instead of creating new app registration for every role, you can just grant **admin consent** to required **[API permissions](https://i.imgur.com/rXroSWx.png)** and generate access token only for them. You will get the **[roles in decoded token](https://i.imgur.com/sweZlL9.png)** based on what you consented.

Comment: I'd still need different app registrations when I need a client to access Admin functionality and another to access only with Read, right? I have tried with the current setup and I don't see the roles in the JWT. I'll try the setup again..

Comment: Please recheck the parameters you are using to generate token. It should be like 
**`client_id`** : AppId of Api dev Client read app and 
**`scope`**: api://AppId of Api dev/.default

Comment: Yes! That's it, I used the scope for the client app not the API app.

Comment: You need to use API app for scope.... You won't get roles if both are swapped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248042/discussion-between-grmbl-and-sridevi).